# Can't push to github repo from Windows 10 WLS (ubuntu)

Tags: git, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I think that it's first time I'm pushing to GitHub from Windows 10 Linux (usually I use ssh and real Linux box).

I can't login I'm using http url for the repo, so I need to type username and password. I've tried to change the password on github because I've thought that I've forget it but typing new password don't work.

Here is the output:

```
$ git push -v
Pushing to https://github.com/jcubic/jquery.terminal.git
Username for 'https://github.com': jcubic
Password for 'https://jcubic@github.com':
remote: Invalid username or password.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/jcubic/jquery.terminal.git/'
```

my `.gitconfig` have my correct email (but this is only for commit command not for push).

Comment: Do you have 2FA enabled on your GitHub account? If so, you'll have to use an [access token](https://help.github.com/en/articles/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line) as your password.

Comment: @EnricoCampidoglio yes I use 2FA, thanks. Maybe I didn't pushed from other machine using http after I've set it up.